# How to call Java code from Liquibase lifecycle?

Tags: liquibase

I would like to run code after changesets have been applied in liquibase.  Basically I need to call a stored procedure my DBA has supplied after a column has been added to a table.  I have been digging through the Liquibase API but have not found anything obvious yet.

Thanks,
Ransom

Comment: Most obvious to me: Use the [`sql` change](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html) to call the stored procedure and put/include this to the very end of your master script?
But I guess you already came across this. Is it necessary that the SP only runs when a new column has been added?

Comment: Yeah, that just felt prone to human error, if someone forgets then things are in an unhappy state

Answer (score 0):

Had some time to play with liquibase some more this morning and came up with this, which is not great, but should work for what I have right now.

```
    Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));
    Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("update.xml", new FileSystemResourceAccessor(), database);
    List<ChangeSet> changeSets = liquibase.listUnrunChangeSets(null);
    liquibase.update(null);
    for (RanChangeSet ranChangeSet: database.getRanChangeSetList()) {
        ChangeSet found = null;
        for (ChangeSet changeSet: changeSets) {
            if (ranChangeSet.isSameAs(changeSet)) {
                found = changeSet;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (found == null) {
            // ran previously
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println(ranChangeSet.getChangeLog());
        for (Change change: found.getChanges()) {
            if (change instanceof CreateTableChange) {
                System.out.println(( (CreateTableChange)change ).getTableName());
            }
            // handle others
        }
    }
```